# Why I don't see metrics for all SQS queues in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to set up CloudWatch alarm on the size of specific queue, but I can only see metrics for one queue in the list. How can I see metrics for all queues?

Answer (score 1):

SQS Only generates metrics for queues which are "active".  Try making some requests against the queue (ReceiveMessage for example) and then see if you start getting cloudwatch metrics.